# how to get all non null values from array in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i'm printing all non null values from array which contain null values. i want to print only non null values

```
string a = "welcome";

var rm = new string [] {null,"hai",null,"15"};

Console.WriteLine("{0}",!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rm[0])? a 
:!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rm[1]) ? a +":"+ rm[1] : 
!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rm[2]) ? a +":"+ rm[1]+ ":"+rm[2] : a +":"+ rm[1]+ 
":"+rm[2]+":"+rm[3] );
```

actual output : welcome:hai

Expected output : welcome:hai:15

Comment: `string.Join(rm.Where(T => T != null), ":")`

Comment: `using System.Linq; var filtered = rm.Where( elem => ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(elem))` to filter to what you want to print, then use string.Join.

Comment: are you looking specifically for a linq solution? have you tried using a loop ?

Comment: @AgentFire the separator comes first, then the collection ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get and `IEnumerable` representing all non-null and non-empty values by using the [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) method.

Your array is called `rm` so you could get the `IEnumerable` like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> nonNullNonEmptyValues = rm.Where(e => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e));
```

If you want to join them like in your example you can use [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) like this (@AgentFire has an error in his comment since this method actually takes the separator first, then the values):

```
String joined = String.Join(":", nonNullNonEmptyValues);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want using a loop, it will your solution:

```
string a = "welcome";

var rm = new string [] {null,"hai",null,"15"};
for(int i = 0; i < rm.Length; i++)
{
  if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(rm[i])
    a += ":" + rm[i];
}
Console.WriteLine(a);
```